How to be notified of a garbage collection operation?
In a complex .NET application, I have some suspicious timing issues in a critical section of code, and I suspect a garbage collection may be the issue.  I would like to log a line when a GC is occurring, so I tried the GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(), GC.WaitForFullGCApproach() and GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() functions, but I never get notified.
I tried to duplicate the issue with the following program (AI-generated, but similar to my tests):
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
   {
   static void Main(string[] args)
      {
      // Register for full garbage collection notification
      GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10, 10);

      // Start a separate thread to monitor GC notifications
      Thread gcMonitorThread = new Thread(WatchForGCNotification);
      gcMonitorThread.IsBackground = true;
      gcMonitorThread.Start();

      Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to force memory pressure and trigger a full GC...");
      Console.ReadLine();

      // Force memory pressure to trigger GC
      ForceGarbageCollection();

      Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
      Console.ReadLine();
      }

   static void WatchForGCNotification()
      {
      while (true)
         {
         // Wait for GC to approach
         GCNotificationStatus status = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();

         if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("GC is approaching...");

            // Wait for GC to complete
            status = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

            if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
               {
               Console.WriteLine("Full GC completed.");
               }
            else if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Canceled)
               {
               Console.WriteLine("GC was canceled.");
               }
            else
               {
               Console.WriteLine("GC failed.");
               }
            }
         else if (status == GCNotificationStatus.Canceled)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("GC approach was canceled.");
            }
         else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("GC approach failed.");
            }

         // Small delay to prevent tight loop
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         }
      }

   static void ForceGarbageCollection()
      {
      // Allocate a large amount of memory to force garbage collection
      const int numObjects = 1000000;
      object[] objects = new object[numObjects];

      for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
         {
         objects[i] = new byte[1024]; // Allocate 1 KB per object
         }

      // Remove references to allocated objects
      for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
         {
         objects[i] = null;
         }

      // Manually trigger GC
      GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
      }
   }

Am I doing something wrong, or it's just that the way a garbage collect is forced is incorrect?
Thank you.

Did you read Microsoft's documentation on the subject? They have a pretty thorough write up on how to do this...

I read the function documentation, but not that page.  I'll test it thanks!

"Heretic Monkey" gave a link to the Microsoft documentation page that contains a sample program to monitor for GC events and force the situation to occur:
garbage-collection/notifications
To have a notification, the sample must allocate enough memory to fill up my entire RAM.  And even doing that, I only get "Approaching" notification; no full GC occurs.
It would have been useful to get notifications about simple garbage collect operations, but it looks like not possible.  Instead, we can only poll GC.CollectionCount().
